# Using spring security 4.2 and tomcat 8.5 no session is created on password success

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, tomcat, spring-security

So my login page posts to the login action and proceeds to the success url, but no session is created and the only role available both before and after is ROLE_ANONYMOUS  below are my local and tomcat contexts.

```
 <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>

            <security:user-service>
                <security:user disabled="false" locked="false" name="user" password="pass" authorities="USER,ROLE_USER,SUPERUSER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:http pattern="/views/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/templates/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/js/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/img/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/fonts/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/css/*" security="none"/>
    <security:http use-expressions="true" create-session="always" once-per-request="true" auto-config="true" >

        <security:intercept-url pattern='/businesses' access='hasRole("ROLE_USER")' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/products' access='hasRole("ROLE_USER")' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/api' access='hasRole("ROLE_USER")' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/login.jsp' access='permitAll' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/login' access='permitAll' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
        <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/business" default-target-url='/'
                    always-use-default-target='false' />
    </security:http>

<Context sessionCookiePath="/" >

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```